# Why does this function pointer assignment work when assigned directly but not with the conditional operator?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, overloading

(No #include's were used for this example, compiled on MacOS10.14, Eclipse IDE, with g++, options -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0)

Assuming this variable declaration:

```
int (*fun)(int);
```

This fails to compile with "invalid overload of std::toupper and std::tolower".

```
fun = (1 ? std::toupper : std::tolower);   // ERROR, invalid overload
```

And this compiles OK:

```
if (1) {
    fun = std::toupper;   // OK
}
else {
    fun = std::tolower;   // OK
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195997/discussion-on-question-by-ph-h-why-does-this-function-pointer-assignment-work-wh).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`std::toupper`([1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) and [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/toupper)) and `std::tolower`([1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) and [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower)) are overloaded. When determining the common type between them for the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) (before the assignment to `chr2fun`), which overloading should be used can't be determined.

You can use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) to specify which one should be considered. (Presicely, to force the [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) happens at first respectively, then the trouble in determining the common type disappears.)

> `static_cast` may also be used to disambiguate function overloads by performing a function-to-pointer conversion to specific type

e.g.

```
chr2fun = (str2modus == STR2UP ? static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper) 
                               : static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::tolower));
```

For the 2nd case, `chr2fun` is assigned directly; the type of `chr2fun` is explicit and the correct overloading would be selected in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address).

(emphasis mine)

> In all these contexts, the function selected from the overload set is the function whose type matches the pointer to function, reference to function, or pointer to member function type that is expected by target: the object or reference being initialized, **the left-hand side of the assignment**, function or operator parameter, the return type of a function, the target type of a cast, or the type of the template parameter, respectively.

Comment: Adding to the answer, using them without std:: works.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis it's unspecified whether that works, if `#include <cctype>` was used (the implementation must place the names in `std` but can optionally also place them in global namespace)

Comment: @MartinBonner I tried, but both are required. https://wandbox.org/permlink/NLB23HjYBiReU7Tx

Comment: @songyuanyao That's actually a case for another "why?". :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It's not easy to answer... I think it's just the standard doesn't require the compiler to do this; it might require more complex analyses.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Usually the reason for "optionally place in global namespace" is because different real implementations do things differently, and putting a requirement to either mandate or forbid this would put undue implementation effort on some implementations.  (I have a bit set that C++98 tried to insist on "std:: only" with some headers, and nearly all implementations went ahead and ignored them because it was too hard to integrate with existing C libraries like that.)

Comment: @MartinBonner -- that's exactly right. Back in C++03 the C++ versions of the standard C headers were not allowed to put the function names into the global namespace. That rule was changed because it would have produced major implementation headaches if any standard library implementor actually followed it.

Answer (score 12):

In the first case, the compiler balks before even getting to the assignment. A simplified expression:

```
(true ? std::toupper : std::tolower)
```

Will fail to compile if there are multiple overloads of `toupper`/`tolower` present. This is because the ternary operator's return type must be established based solely on the types of 2nd and 3rd argument, without ever looking at the context where the result of it is used.

Funny enough, even if one of those arguments *isn't* an overloaded function, that's still not enough. Reasons for that are less obvious, and have more to do with [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address)<sup>1</sup> rules and where they apply. A cast is precisely one of seven possibilities to trigger it, and determining the target type of ternary operators itself isn't.

In the case of direct assignment, the rhs of assignment must fit the lhs, and so there's no ambiguity.

**Either way**, as pointed out by @Caleth, according to [16.5.4.2.1.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#6), this code has unspecified behaviour.

---

<sup>1</sup>The C++ Reference has an incorrect C++ Standard paragraph. [over.over] is actually 12.4.

Comment: thx, thats real useful info, but int this case, toupper and tolower have identical signatures...?

Comment: @phh They have identical *sets* of signatures because of their overloads. Which matching pair should be used to determine the final type of `?:`?

Comment: omg, am i a beginner! thx a lot, that answered my question!! :-)

Comment: Caleth's reference is from the draft C++2a. What before that?

Answer (score 1):

This [snippet](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zDBHrg) compiles fine with gcc 9.1

```
#include <cctype>

int chr2fun(bool str2modus) {
    const bool STR2UP = true;
    int (*chr2fun)(int);

    if (str2modus == STR2UP) {
        chr2fun = std::toupper;
    } else {
        chr2fun = std::tolower;
    }
    chr2fun = (str2modus == STR2UP ? std::toupper : std::tolower);
}
```

On what platform and with which compiler do you get the error?

Comment: I suspect it will turn out they have `<locale>` included which introduces extra overloads for `std::toupper` etc.